# Fetching, modifying information on binary file?

Tags: c++, database, file-io, fstream

I have a binary file whose size is "x+a+y" bytes. I have some questions;

- Without exhaustive reading x bytes, How can I jump to start point of a bytes ?
- Without taking all of the information reside in a line and then doing required modification and finally writing new information to the same line, How can I just change "a bytes" of the data in place whose starting address is shown as P?
- Can I put a pointer to a starting point of "a bytes" that is to P ?

Question about how data is stored in pile file;

- Why is all of the primitive data type ( such as int ) stored in pile file preferred to be unsigned ?
- Why is offset  always chosen as unsigned int ? 
  eX:  x,a,y are known value

  ```
  ___________________________________________________________
  |                             |     |                     |
  |                             |     |                     |
  |----------> x <--------------|> a <|-------> y <---------|
                                ^
                                ^
                                P
  ```

Platform linux

Note: If I do dublicate question, please inform me so that I can delete this question.
      Feel free when you command smth

Comment: [Find Working Code for Fetching, modifying information on binary file in the link:][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12406355/559746

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in `ifstream` called `seekg` that moves the read-position to a specific place in the file. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg.

Comment: seekg  is for reading and seekp for writing which is what he needs.

Comment: If he need to both read and write, using `fstream` then it uses the methods from `istream` for seaking.

Comment: But `seekg` only works in limited ways.  Above all, to seek to an arbitrary position, the file must be opened in binary mode.  (Otherwise, you can only seek to a position which you've obtained by `tellg`.)  And of course, depending on the file type, `seekg` might not work at all (e.g. if the file is a terminal).

Comment: @JamesKanze The title of the question contains the words "binary file", so I guess the file will be open in binary mode, in which case `seekg` is good to skip X bytes at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That seems obvious to you and me, but it seems worth mentioning to someone who's also unaware of the existence of `seekg`.